# Definitions, theorems, … with description inside a box and the title above the box

Tags: theorems

I am searching for a definition (or similar) environment with the following features:

- Numbering
- Listing
- Definition title with number above the description
- Definition text inside a box with black border

It should look like the following example:

[image: Definition box with heading]

I tried to use `amsthm` and `thmtools` (which has `\newframedtheorem`, but titles get also framed) and like their numbering features but was not able to adjust the style.

Comment: Since you have not accepted an answer yet: Do you miss something in the given answers?

Comment: I like the answers and I will accept one as soon as I win the fight with `tcolorbox`. The systems I am working with provide only `tcolorbox 2.40` (or even older) which lack options required by your answer. I downloaded `tcolorbox 2.80` and put it in a directory `libs/tcolorbox`. The problem is that `tcolorbox` includes its own `tex` files, so I have to copy them into the working directory (where the document's `tex` files are stored) or use the environment variable `TEXINPUTS`. I am searching for a solution without the environment variable and without throwing files into the working directory.

Comment: For a such a case, you can try an undocumented trick. Use `\def\tcbpkgprefix{libs/tcolorbox/}` **before** `\usepackage[most]{libs/tcolorbox/tcolorbox}`. Thus, the libraries are found without setting an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that (based on `tcolorbox`)?
You can remove the `cleveref` options, if you do not need or like them.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum,cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,
  crefname={definition}{definitions},Crefname={Definition}{Definitions}% only for cleveref
  ]{mydef}{Definition}{%
  enhanced,frame hidden,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
  interior style={fill=none,draw=black,line width=0.6pt},
  left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
  terminator sign colon}{def}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

See something in \Cref{def:AREF} or \Cref{def:BREF}.

\begin{mydef}{}{AREF}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}{}{BREF}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first example code aligned the box frames with the surrounding text. Alternatively, the boxed text could be aligned with the normal page content. The following code shows another implementation which may be nicer for breaking the boxes, if you should look for this. Finally, a list of definitions is given.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum,cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=mytheorems,
  crefname={definition}{definitions},Crefname={Definition}{Definitions}% only for cleveref
  ]{mydef}{Definition}{%
  enhanced jigsaw,breakable,oversize,interior hidden,colframe=black,
  boxrule=0.6pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxsep=1mm,
  terminator sign colon,description delimiters parenthesis,separator sign none,
  detach title,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enlarge top by=1.2\baselineskip,enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=0mm,
  overlay unbroken and first={\node[anchor=base west,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0.6pt,yshift=4pt]
    at (frame.north west) {\tcbtitle};},
  }{def}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

See something in \Cref{def:AREF}, \Cref{def:BREF} or \Cref{def:CREF}.

\begin{mydef}{My title}{AREF}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{mydef}{}{BREF}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mydef}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{mydef}{Another one}{CREF}
\lipsum[5]
\end{mydef}

\tcblistof[\chapter]{mytheorems}{List of Definitions and Theorems}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Alternatively, the same output is achieved with the following more elegant code relying on `tcolorbox v3.00 (2014/05/08)`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}%  version 3.00 (2014/05/09) and above

\usepackage{lipsum,cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=mytheorems,
  crefname={definition}{definitions},Crefname={Definition}{Definitions}% only for cleveref
  ]{mydef}{Definition}{%
  enhanced jigsaw,breakable,oversize,interior hidden,colframe=black,
  boxrule=0.6pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxsep=1mm,pad at break=0pt,
  terminator sign colon,description delimiters parenthesis,separator sign none,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1mm},minipage boxed title,
  boxed title style={empty,boxrule=0.6pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm},
  coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,before title=\strut}{def}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

See something in \Cref{def:AREF}, \Cref{def:BREF} or \Cref{def:CREF}.

\begin{mydef}{My title}{AREF}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{mydef}{}{BREF}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mydef}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{mydef}{Another one}{CREF}
\lipsum[5]
\end{mydef}

\tcblistof[\chapter]{mytheorems}{List of Definitions and Theorems}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) this time:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{defi}
\numberwithin{defi}{chapter}
\newmdenv[
settings={\refstepcounter{defi}},
singleextra={
  \node[
    overlay,
    inner xsep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    font=\bfseries
    ] at ([xshift=5pt]O|-P) {Definition~\thedefi:};
  },
firstextra={
  \node[
    overlay,
    inner xsep=0pt,
    anchor=south west,
    font=\bfseries
    ] at ([xshift=5pt]O|-P) {Definition~\thedefi:};
  },
skipabove=4.5ex,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=-5pt,
rightmargin=-5pt,
]{mydef}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mydef}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]