# Problem with latex box

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I defined a new command in order to create an empty box with a title. The code is the following:

```
  \newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
\textbf{\emph{#1}}
\vspace{2mm}
{\centering\fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \hfill\vspace{#2}
        \end{minipage}
}   }
}
```

The problem is that when I used this exact same code without the new command I defined, the output was what I expected - a bold italic title and below that, an empty box.

However, when I use it with the new command, fox example `\mybox{Title}{1in}` the box is next to the title! It is very confusing!

I would appreciate your help, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Besides the direct answer already given, I would recommend to use a package like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` to create a titled box. There are many examples here for both packages. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169096/definitions-theorems-with-description-inside-a-box-and-the-title-above-the-b is quite similar to your box (plus a numbering which can be removed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really explain the technical reason I think, but add a `\par` after the title.

You also want to set the width of the `minipage` to `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep`. This is because `\fbox` inserts some space between the frame and content. And finally, you need some `%` at the end of some lines, to avoid spurious spaces, see e.g. [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453), [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) and [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{%
\textbf{\emph{#1}}\par
\vspace{2mm}
{\centering\fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
            \hfill\vspace{#2}
        \end{minipage}%
}}%
}
\begin{document}

\mybox{Title}{1in}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vspace` doesn't start a new paragraph.